# No overload method takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionDetection : MonoBehaviour {
    public Collision c;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        OnCollisionEnter ();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c){     
        if (c.gameObject.name == "Wall") {
            Movement.MoveDirection = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

I can pass the parameter `Collision c` but i cant pass it back as an argument, when I do I get the error `expected 3` with a bunch of syntax on my screen such as: `Expected )`, `Expected ;`

Comment: what do you mean `i cant pass it back as an argument` ? can you post the code?

Comment: You should not be manually calling `OnCollisionEnter`, it is called by Unity automatically when the rigidbody collides with another rigid body.

Comment: Thank you Ron, I didnt know unity called it automatically

Comment: @Kian When working with something new, it never hurts to [double-check the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html). It's worth noting that only one object needs a rigidbody to trigger this event, but both need colliders.

Comment: By the way, your `public Collision c` is not associated with the parameter `Collision c` in the method. You probably do not need the `public Collision c`, so it can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Your method signature doesn't match the invocation.  In detail:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c) {
    ...
}
```

Does not match the usage just above where you're invoking it (in `Update`):

```
OnCollisionEnter ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove two lines
Public coliision c
Oncollision enter()

Everything fine